# asp - browser downloads file instead of displaying

Tags: iis, asp-classic

I am trying to learn ASP.
I set up IIS on my Windows 7 machine and now I am trying to write some simple code.

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\iisstart.htm
```

displays fine, but when I request
    C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWeb\test1.asp
the browser prompts to download the file instead of displaying "Hello World"
This is the code I used:

```
<html>
<body>
<%
response.write("Hello World!")
%>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't think there is something wrong with the code.. Could have I messed up some configurations?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like when you installed IIS you did not tick the optional extras that include asp, for example, when you tick "Internet Information Services", it does not select ASP etc unless you drill down into "Application Development Features" and tick them manually:

[image]

Also, to be clear, if you want to develop in classic asp (*.asp files), you only need ASP, but if you want to start serving ASP.net (*.aspx) files tick ASP.net.

Strictly speaking, there is no harm installing all of the Application Development Features.